# How to make a 3D chart in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I found the [same question](https://superuser.com/questions/568012/xyz-3d-chart-in-excel) but I'm not getting a 3D looking chart as posted in the answer.

[image: Click to see what i'm getting]

My data looks like this:

```
      5    7    11    15   19
0.1   28   21   12    9     7
0.2   22   14   9     5     5
0.3   20   10   6     4     4
0.4   5    4    4     4     4
0.5   4    3    3     3     3
0.6   3    3    3     3     3
0.7   3    3    3     3     3
1.7   2    2    2     2     2
1.9   2    2    2     2     2
```

- Horizontal = X
- Vertical = Y
- Data inside: Z

Is there a way I can turn this into an XYZ-3D chart?

Answer (score 5):

Excel 2013 does not have many charts that support a Z axis (and data visualisation experts are grateful for that. No more cylinder or pyramid cylinder eye candy junk).

The only two are a 3D Column chart and the surface chart. If you need a 3D scatter chart as linked to in your comment to Johnny Wright's answer, then it cannot be done in Excel, as Johnny Wright correctly states.

A chart like the below should be avoided, because it is impossible to tell the value of a column in the 3D layout.

[image]

Comment: +1 for **Avoiding 3D charts**.  Consider alternatives like panel charts for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the answer to the question you linked to, the accepted answer actually says *"What you want may be outside the ability of Excel. Perhaps look into Mathmatica for more advanced 3-D graphing solutions."*

I had a go and couldn't get it to work either so first it seems Excel is out of the question. Secondly, I can't see from your data how you would make a 3D chart anyway; whats the data for your X,Y,Z axes? In the question you linked to it is clear what data is for each of the axes;

```
    X   Y   Z
N1  2   5   6
N2  2   7   8
N3  0   1   2
N4  0   4   5
N5  9   10  10
N6  4   9   9
N7  0   2   4
N8  0   7   8
N9  0   7   8
```

From your post I can't make out what data is what.

Comment: that's because you didn't read it fully. it says:
Horizontal = X
Vertical = Y
Data inside: Z

Comment: I did read it fully but it does not make sense. What does that mean? If you mean " 5 7 11 15 19" is Horizontal, "0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1.7, 1.9" is vertical and all the other numbers are data inside then it can't be done.
Every piece of data needs three attributes; X, Y and Z. So that means that there should be the same amount of numbers for X, Y and Z (As is the case in the answer you linked to).
From what you have said (how I interpreted it anyway), you have `5` figures for `X`, `9` figures for `Y` and `45` figures for `Z`.

Comment: For example; in the table shown in my answer; the first result is at position `X=2, Y=5, Z=6`. Tell me the position of your first result from your data so I can try and understand your table.

Comment: @Johnny Wright again: horizontal is x, vertical is y, data inside is z. that means, for example: (5,0.1,28) is a point. (0.5,11,3) is another point (x=0.5 , y=11, z=3)

Comment: and you can't say it's impossible. I've done in with another program: http://i90.photobucket.com/albums/k274/alaa_137/Untitled_zps994b8098.png

Comment: **If you mean " 5 7 11 15 19" is Horizontal, "0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 1.7, 1.9" is vertical and all the other numbers are data inside then it can't be done.** I said clearly **IF** thats what you mean. In my opinion you didn't lay the data out very clearly and were very reluctant to explain to me how you had laid it out and you were rude with your responses. 
I'm done here.