# Draw 3D bar plot in Mathematica

Tags: mathematica

I want to draw a 3D bar plot in mathematica as shown in the following link

[XYZ 3D-chart in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/568012/xyz-3d-chart-in-excel)

How do you create a grid and create a cylinder chart? I was able to do in a different way in Mathematica but it was not as good as provided in the above link.

Comment: Can you please provide the *Mathematica* version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Creating something like this yourself is really easy in this case. Make a function that creates a colored `Cylinder` for all your data points and then wrap `Graphics3D` around it with the options you like. Here is an example:

```
testData = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {20, 3}];
Graphics3D[
 Function[{x, y, z}, 
   {RandomColor[], Cylinder[{{x, y, 0}, {x, y, z}}, 0.5]}] @@@ testData, 
 FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, Boxed -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]