# Higher Dimensional Trendline

Tags: microsoft-excel, trendlines

My data is in multiple dimensions, as below. Rather than a trend*line*, I guess I need a trend*plane*. Is this possible in Excel or a similar tool?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do a best fit based on 3D data but you can do a best fit based on each series and then create a 3D surface based on that. Is it acceptable to have it be in a different chart? Smashing a surface on top of an already busy 3D chart would probably be bad UI anyway. First, here's what my final sheet looks like:

[image: Screenshot 1]

I used a 3rd degree polynomial fit such that the surface would be of the form `y = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d`. Based on your data, you may want more or less but you can adapt this proof-of-concept to fit your need. Here's the formulas for the cells `L2:L6`:

```
=INDEX(LINEST(B$2:B$9,$A$2:$A$9^{1,2,3},1,0),1)
=INDEX(LINEST(B$2:B$9,$A$2:$A$9^{1,2,3},1,0),2)
=INDEX(LINEST(B$2:B$9,$A$2:$A$9^{1,2,3},1,0),3)
=INDEX(LINEST(B$2:B$9,$A$2:$A$9^{1,2,3},1,0),4)
=INDEX(LINEST(B$2:B$9,$A$2:$A$9^{1,2,3},1,1),3,1)
```

If you wanted a second degree polynomial, the array would be `{1,2}` and the `row_num` parameter for the `INDEX` function would only go up to 3. These formulas need to be dragged out to the right so that you get a fit for each series. Finally, you can create a second table that calculates this best fit for each point. The formula for cell `V2` is:

```
=L$2*$U2^3+L$3*$U2^2+L$4*$U2+L$5
```

... and that gets dragged down and over. Create a 3D surface chart based on that data and you're done.

Comment: Interesting. But this doesn't give me a 2-dimensional trendline/trendplane, does it?

Comment: It's giving you a 2D trendline for each series and then your presenting that group of trendlines as a surface. It's not perfect but I don't know an easy way in Excel to calculate a best fit point based on points all around it in 3D space instead of just those in a series.

Answer (score 1):

Excel does not have 3D fitting capability. But XLSurfFit, a third party Excel addin can do it pretty easily: http://3dexcel.com/excel-3d-surface-equation-fittinng/

Answer (score 0):

Source [Change the display of a 3-D chart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-display-of-a-3-D-chart-60c13909-d2a1-4e06-8b8c-bccba7868c9b?CorrelationId=ee9cf29c-1ed3-4f53-bb9f-a3aa193db32c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

> **Create a 3-D chart**
>
> - On the worksheet, select the cells that contain the data that you want to use for the chart.
> - On the Insert tab, in the Charts group, do one of the following:
>
>   - To create a 3-D column chart, click Column, and then under 3-D Column, click 3-D Column.
>   - To create a 3-D cylinder chart, click Column, and then under Cylinder, click 3-D Cylinder.
>   - To create a 3-D cone chart, click Column, and then under Cone, click 3-D Cone.
>   - To create a 3-D pyramid chart, click Column, and then under Pyramid, click 3-D Pyramid.
>   - To create a 3-D line chart, click Line, and then under 3-D Line, click 3-D Line.
>   - To create a 3-D area chart, click Area, and then under 3-D Area, click 3-D Area.
>   - To create a 3-D surface chart, click Other Charts, and then under Surface, click 3-D Surface or Wireframe 3-D Surface.

Example:

[image]

See also [XYZ 3D-chart in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/568012/xyz-3d-chart-in-excel), [3D-histogram in Excel](http://excelgraphs.blogspot.nl/2013/04/3d-histogram-in-excel.html) , [3 axis chart](http://best-excel-tutorial.com/56-charts/207-three-axis-chart) and [excel 3d bar chart](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+graphs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=excel+3d+bar+chart) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the higher dimensional trend?

Comment: Trendlines cannot be added to 3D charts in Excel :/ I've not been able to find an addon for this ...